# Why does Hyper-V save my running VM when I'm reverting to a checkpoint that was made when it was off?

Tags: hyper-v

When I revert my running VM (by selecting a the checkpoint it was at before booting and choosing 'apply'), I see the VM is saved for a few seconds first.

Can anyone explain why it saves the VM state rather than just 'killing it off somehow'?

Thanks